# How to limit title length with Visual Composer Post Grid

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have a VC Post Grid element on various pages. On one page, it has 4 columns, on another it has 2, for instance. I need to limit the post excerpt and title so that the post blocks are all aligned horizontally. I have managed to limit the post excerpt with the following code in the theme's functions.php file:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 75;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Additionally, I need to find a way to limit the title length. I have been searching for days and trying various methods, but since I am a PHP beginner, I am not 100% what to look for. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted - having the same issue myself!

Comment: No, I'm afraid I never found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with VC but I am sure you can manipulate your VC files to display the title you want. Search VC files and Look for [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) where the posts are displayed in the page. Look for function [the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), this is the function responsible for displaying the post title.

Now instead of displaying the title you can make it return it by using `the_title("", "", false)` then wrap this in a custom function to manipulate the title.

Actually you can use wordpress built in function [wp_trim_words](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2953) or add a custom function of your own and place it in the `functions.php`. For example using `wp_trim_words`:

```
// In index.php file of your theme
wp_trim_words (
    the_title ( "", "", false ),   // Returns the title of the post
    4,    // Number of words to keep
    NULL // Optional. What to append to the trimmed title. Default '&hellip;'
);
```

This modifications is easy for template files but might take more work with VC. Good luck!

Comment: Would this not change the length for all post titles? Just wondering how to target VC Grid elements titles specifically....

Comment: @MhluziBhaka I don't know about VC, but if you wrap your title with `wp_trim_words` in your template files, it will only change the title in this specific template file, not for all post titles. You will have to find the function responsible for displaying the title in your VC files and wrap it. For more info about limiting the title words
[check this article](http://ahmedspace.com/2016/08/04/limiting-excerpt-and-title-length-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally new to this, but I looked awhile for the answer to this question, so I hope it helps someone else.

Instead of limiting the title length, I just increased the minimum height of the title portion of the post grid element.

First I right clicked on the title, and selected "inspect". I messed around until I found the code that controlled the title.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Kgi.png)

Then I copied the code and put this in the CSS, adjusting the min-height until the grids were even.

```css
.vc_custom_heading.vc_gitem-post-data.vc_gitem-post-data-source-post_title {
    min-height: 100px
```